# Thunderbird update not available

Tags: release-hera, updates, security, thunderbird

I'm using elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera and Thunderbird 68.10.0.

Since there's a [security warning on versions prior 78.6.1](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2021-02/) I tried to update, with no success.

- AppCenter has no updates for Thunderbird.
- After `apt update` and `apt upgrade` I tried `apt install --only-upgrade thunderbird`, which resulted in a message saying Thunderbird was already the latest version (1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).

What now? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance - Stefan

Comment: Have you added de repo? `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-stable ` Should have the version you mentioned: 78.6.1esr+build1-0ubuntu0.21.04.1 See details [here](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this. I have made up for it now - it results in AppCenter reporting a new version was available, but that is 1.16.12 only. As expected, upgrading via apt leads to this version, instead of the latest one. Hm...